RabbitMQ messages are stuck in the Ready state
I am facing an issue with RabbitMQ where messages are stuck in the "Ready" state. I have a total of six exchanges configured, but only one of them is not working correctly. Upon further investigation, I noticed that the affected exchange does not have any consumers attached to it. I have already attempted restarting RabbitMQ, but the issue persists, and the messages remain stuck in the "Ready" state for that specific exchange. I would appreciate any guidance or troubleshooting tips to resolve this issue effectively.
